# Invalid or unexpected token on a very simple function

Tags: jquery

what is wrong here:

```
$('#evclose').click(function(){
    console.log('323');
});​ // line 103
```

console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token... commona.js103

when I delete the entire function error does not appear.

Comment: Could be related to code that is above it too... if there are too many brackets or braces on previous lines

Comment: there is some invalid character after `....});---here---​`

Comment: There's an invisible character at the end of the last line. In general, if there is no apparent cause for a syntax error, delete the line and re-write it from scratch without copy-pasting any previous content.

Comment: seems there's at least one error on your javascript that prevent the rest of your scripts to run correctly.

Comment: it's `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` ( char code `8203` )

Comment: @PranavCBalan, how can I check what I press wrongly on keyboard to get this char code 8203 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just a **non-ascii-character \xe2** at the end of your function braces.

Open **developer tool > console** and paste your code. You will see a red dot over there which indicates an invalid character.

Just remove that invalid character (check image below).

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. solved. so what I wrongly press on keyboard ?

Comment: yes may be!! but more it appears in case of copy/paste. cause we require  'alt + code ' in windows  OR 'ctrl + shift + u'  in unix to type it and rarely we use this key combination in normal typing.

Comment: JavaScript uses Unicode so the problem isn't a non-ASCII character, it just a syntax error. As you point out, the difficulty is in being able to see the character.