# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token with jQuery on CountUp Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving this error through my console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token: Line 134

In my jQuery, the line in question is the following:

```
  var options = {
    useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ',',
    decimal: '.',
  };
```

Which is a direct copy + paste from https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/ - which is generated by the website.

Comment: What's the previous line?

Comment: @FZs That is the beginning of the script. The line before is the open <script> tag.

Comment: Guess you have some sort of invisible character in your code like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601384/invalid-or-unexpected-token-on-a-very-simple-function