# Customized Webchat Bot framework V4 Issue

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I've cloned the webchat.js from the repo https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat 
After customizing it I've published it to my Azure domain.
Then I've edited my html code by changing the webchat.js call to new one as follows:
`<script src="https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/forms/bit_bot/js/webchat.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
When I run the html page I get an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' error on the browser.
Here is how my application token has been taken.
`<script>
      (async function () {
       const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'MY BOT SECRET' } });
                const { token } = await res.json();
         window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
               directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine(
                 { token 
               }),
               userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
               username: 'Web Chat User',
               locale: 'en-US',
               botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
               userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
            },
            document.getElementById('webchat')
         );
            })().catch(err => console.error(err));
      </script>`
What could be wrong? 
Thx in advance

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are getting the correct token for your bot and not the sample mockbot?

Comment: Thx.
I guess it's not the case.
My bot works fine while accessing the default cdn but fails when pointing to the custom version.
Please have a look on how the token request has been done in the problem statement above.
Additional thoughts?

Comment: After a quick check it appears it's just talking about a character, not the bot token. See this article for an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601384/invalid-or-unexpected-token-on-a-very-simple-function. I'd check to see if you have a string that's not in quotes or some misplaced brackets somewhere.

Comment: Spot on Bill. There was a kind of ghost character in my code that was generating the error. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Cool, I'll repost that as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

The "token" here is not referring to your Bot Framework Directline token, it's just talking about a (misplaced) character in your code. After a quick check it appears it's just talking about a character, not the bot token. This article has several examples of a similar issue: [Invalid or unexpected token on a very simple function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601384/invalid-or-unexpected-token-on-a-very-simple-function)

I'd check to see if you have a string that's not in quotes, hidden character, or some misplaced brackets somewhere.